# C3P0 pool connection acquisition hangs

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, c3p0

I have a Java based service (deployed as a container in AWS) which loads some data as part of cache hydration at startup. I am using *c3p0* for connection pooling and recently in our QA env, this service started hanging up at startup (there is no code or library change). I restored the QA tag to prod tag to make sure, container image is the same as the working prod container, however, it still did not work.

I recall a similar issue for other service a couple of years back and I was able to fix that with adding an entropy related JVM flag (`-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`), however, even that approach is not working fine.

DB

- Oracle 19.8.0.0

Lib specs:

- c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
- ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar
- orai18n-12.2.0.1.jar

Please see java thread stack:

```
C3p0 pool initialization threads hung up Thread 96: (state = IN_NATIVE)

    sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(boolean, java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)  
    sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(java.net.ProtocolFamily, java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=25, line=482 (Interpreted frame)  
    sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int) @bci=6, line=474 (Interpreted frame)  
    sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(java.net.SocketAddress) @bci=225, line=647 (Interpreted frame)  
    java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(java.net.SocketAddress) @bci=6, line=189 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(java.net.SocketAddress, int) @bci=8, line=99 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.(java.net.SocketAddress, int, oracle.net.nt.NetStatImpl) @bci=33, line=77 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect() @bci=210, line=192 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(java.util.Properties) @bci=69, line=174 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(boolean) @bci=380, line=510 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(java.lang.String, boolean) @bci=311, line=548 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(java.lang.String, boolean) @bci=10, line=682 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) @bci=387, line=309 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(java.lang.String, org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) @bci=1422, line=1596 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) @bci=51, line=588 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) @bci=45, line=793 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) @bci=15, line=57 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties, org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential) @bci=477, line=747 (Interpreted frame)  
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(java.lang.String, java.util.Properties) @bci=4, line=562 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) @bci=18, line=134 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ConnectionCustomizer, java.lang.String) @bci=25, line=182 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) @bci=5, line=171 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource() @bci=50, line=137 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire() @bci=25, line=1014 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool) @bci=1, line=32 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run() @bci=31, line=1810 (Interpreted frame)  
    com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run() @bci=121, line=547 (Interpreted frame)
```

Application layer timeout as it is not able to get connection from pool.

TIA.

Comment: It looks like the attempt to connect to the DB (within the Oracle driver, not c3p0) is hanging indefinitely. On AWS, this happens easily if there is a security group misconfiguration, if the connection is not properly authorized.

Comment: So, this is an ec2 instance, which hosts multiple services (container).  Only this service has suddenly stopped working. That should eliminate security group aspect. @SteveWaldman